# Find duplicate object by property and Merge using Javascript or UnderscoreJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array as mentioned below:

```
var somevalue = [{
    code: 1,
    name: 'a1'
  }, {
    code: 2,
    name: 'b1'
  }, {
    code: 1,
    name: 'a2'
  },
  {
    code: 1,
    name: 'a3'
  },
  {
    code: 2,
    name: 'b2'
  }
]
```

From this array, I want to find duplicate element by `code` and merge all elements of the same code into one. So the final output would be:

```
var somevalue = [{
    code: 1,
    name: 'a1, a2'
  }, {
    code: 2,
    name: 'b1, b2, b3'
  }
]
```

is there any way to achieve this using `underscoreJS` ?

I can do this by `for-loop`. But In real scenario, its very large array containing JSON object of having 10 properties. So I need some performance oriented solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array.reduce:

```js
var datas = [{
    code: 1,
    name: 'a1'
  }, {
    code: 2,
    name: 'b1'
  }, {
    code: 1,
    name: 'a2'
  },
  {
    code: 1,
    name: 'a3'
  },
  {
    code: 2,
    name: 'b2'
  }
];

datas = datas.reduce((m, o) => {
  const found = m.find(e => e.code === o.code);
  found ? found.name += `, ${o.name}` : m.push(o);
  return m;
}, []);

console.log(datas);
```